# React Bootstrap- Overlay Tooltip rendering in wrong position initially

Tags: javascript, overlay, react-bootstrap

I am writing a react bootstrap app where a button appears at the end of an animation. When the button first appears, I want a tooltip to appear next to it. Once the user hovers over and off the button, the tooltip should go away and re-appear whenever the user hovers over the button again. I've gotten this to work as desired, but when I position the button where I want it to be (fixed to the bottom of the screen), the tooltip initially renders in the wrong position (where the button was before being positioned).

I have created two simple examples to demonstrate this behavior.

In the first example, the button is positioned at the top of the screen and the tooltip behaves as this desire:

```
function Testing(){
    const refLink = useRef(null);

    const [overlayOpen, setOverlayOpen]  = useState(true); // Initially open
    const [textDone, setTextDone] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            setTextDone(true)
        },1000)
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    },[])
    return(
        <Container>
            <Row>
                {textDone ?
                    <>
                    <Button ref={refLink} onMouseOver={() => setOverlayOpen(true)}
                            onMouseOut={() => setOverlayOpen(false)}
                    >
                        <FaComment/>
                    </Button>
                    <Overlay target={refLink.current} show={overlayOpen}
                             onHide={() => setOverlayOpen(false)} rootClose placement={"bottom"}>
                        <Tooltip>
                            Submit a personal response!
                        </Tooltip>
                    </Overlay>
                    </>
                    : ''
                }
            </Row>
        </Container>
   )
}

export default Testing
```

The `textDone` state is set to true once the "animation" finishes. To simplify the example, I omitted the animation itself and recreated the delay with `setTimeout`.

The second example is identical except for the following .css class added to the Row element in which the button, overlay, and tooltip are nested inside of.

```
.fixed-button{
    position:fixed;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

With this addition, the button ends up where I want it, but the tooltip first appears at the top of the screen. Once I hover over the button, the tooltip moves to the correct position.

Here are some gifs of the two examples.

[Example 1 (tooltip behaving as intended but button not positioned in right spot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzne3.gif)

[Example 2 (button positioned where I want it but tooltip initially showing up in wrong spot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waLfi.gif)

My question is: how can I get the tooltip to initially appear in the correct position?

Comment: _"...not rendering in wrong position initially"_: How do you know it's in the wrong position if it's not rendering? You may want to revise your question title.

Comment: You're right, the title doesn't make sense. Let me fix that.